# Allow IP Address Range In hosts.allow

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, unix, centos5

I would like to allow this Ip Range `94.1.1.1 to 94.15.255.255`

I tried inputting this in the hosts.allow file after reading [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/linux/3175193.htm) that you need to use networks and netmasks? i don't know much about this so i don't know what i have done wrong.

```
94.1.1.1/255.255.255.255
```

but it did not work.

What should i be putting in the file to make it allow that ip range?

Thanks

Comment: See also section `PATTERNS` of `man hosts.allow`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this [subnetting calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=94.1.1.1&mask1=12&mask2=) I get

94.1.1.1/12

as the value to put in your hosts.allow

Comment: thanks, but didn't work for some reason

Comment: @James:In what way does it not work ?

Comment: Well i remote logged in to my home pc to test it, and it didn't let me in, but when i changed it to 94.0.0.0/255.240.0.0 it worked. Maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: That calculator is incredibly useful, ty

Answer (score 6):

The Correct answer which I tested and is working is as follows.

```
94.1.  # (just leave everything after the dot .)
```

In the case if you are manually editing the *host.allow* file.

Anything you put like / will be not allowed in host file as per my experiments.

If you want to allow your ip range the code should be look like this.

```
whostmgrd :94.1. :allow
whostmgrd : ALL : deny
```

This will prevent WHM login and allow only IP starting from *94.1*.
Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be able to use `94.0.0.0/12` or `94.0.0.0/255.240.0.0`

Comment: thanks, but both didn't work for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I had a little mistake there, you must use 94.0.0.0/255.240.0.0, You must use the network address, 94.0.0.0 in this case. I glad you has figured it out by yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

using a mixture of what you both put, i managed to get it.

it was 94.0.0.0/255.240.0.0